# How to use the Entity Framework connection string in log4net?

Tags: entity-framework, connection-string, log4net

Is there any way to configure the connection string of log4net and to use the same connection string of entity framework?

This is my entity framework connection string:

```
<add name="EntityFrameworkConnection" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Data.BinAppModel.csdl|res://*/Data.BinAppModel.ssdl|res://*/Data.BinAppModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\sqlexpress;initial catalog=database;user id=user;password=pwd;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

This is my log4net configuration

```
<connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data,  Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />

<connectionStringName value="EntityFrameworkConnection" />
```

But I get this error:

```
log4net:ERROR [AdoNetAppender] ErrorCode: GenericFailure. Could not open database connection [metadata=res://*/Data.BinAppModel.csdl|res://*/Data.BinAppModel.ssdl|res://*/Data.BinAppModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string="data source=data source=.\sqlexpress;initial catalog=database;user id=user;password=pwd;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;"]. Connection string context [ConnectionStringName].
```

Comment: No, you will have to have the `provider connection string` section as a normal connection string.

Answer (score 4):

If you are willing to do a little coding, you could do the following:

1. Create a simple class that inherits from `log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender` and override the method `CreateConnection`
2. Change log4net configuration to use your new EFNetAppender class
3. Change log4net 'connectionType' element to use EF connection factory
4. Change any other place in the configuration to EFNetAppender

EFNetAppender class:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using log4net;

namespace YourNamespace
{
   public class EFNetAppender : log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender
   {
      protected override IDbConnection CreateConnection(Type connectionType, string connectionString)
      {
          var factory = (IDbConnectionFactory)Activator.CreateInstance(connectionType);
          IDbConnection instance = factory.CreateConnection(connectionString);
          instance.ConnectionString = connectionString;
          return instance;
      }
   }
}
```

Log4Net configuration:

```
<log4net>
  <appender name="EFNetAppender" type="YourNamespace.EFNetAppender">
     <connectionType value="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
     <connectionStringName value="EntityFrameworkConnection" />
     ...
     ...
  <appender>
  <root>
      ...
      <appender-ref ref="EFNetAppender" />
      ...
  </root>
```

I tested with EF version 6.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Klinger, you really helped me out with this

Answer (score 2):

In continue to @Klinger's answer:

I've faced an issue that was caused by the EntityFramework connectionString (the one with metadata... as in the OP). An exception was thrown when trying to 
create connection with the message about metadata not a keyword.

What I had to do is extract the provider's connection string and pass it to both the factory.CreateConnection function and the instance.ConnectionString property, as seen in the below code.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

namespace AdvancedPackagesTracker.DataAccess
{
    public class EFNetAppender : log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender
    {
        protected override IDbConnection CreateConnection(Type connectionType, string connectionString)
        {
            var factory = (IDbConnectionFactory)Activator.CreateInstance(connectionType);

            var builder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
            var providerConnectionString = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString).ProviderConnectionString;
            IDbConnection instance = factory.CreateConnection(providerConnectionString);
            instance.ConnectionString = providerConnectionString;
            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```