# I configured Log4Net with Entity Framework 6 memory slowly creeps up?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, service, log4net

I created a CSV file splitter to be able to manipulate the file prior processing.
I wanted to remove the file appender from Log4Net and place it in the database since this is
installed as a service.

I use some info from this thread [How to use the Entity Framework connection string in log4net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33845799/how-to-use-the-entity-framework-connection-string-in-log4net)

Everything I found before this makes changes to the constructor which I wanted to avoid.

Here is the SQL Create Table Script used to create the logging table in SQL which and be added to the entity .edmx

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Log4NetLog](  
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,  
    [Date] [datetime] NOT NULL,  
    [Thread] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,  
    [Level] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,  
    [Logger] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,  
    [Message] [varchar](4000) NOT NULL,  
    [Exception] [varchar](2000) NULL,  
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Log4NetLog] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED   
(  
    [Id] ASC  
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]  
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Here is my log4net section in the app.config file:

```
<log4net>
      <appender name="EFNetAppender" type="CSCFileService.EFNetAppender">
          <bufferSize value="1" />
          <connectionType value="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
          <connectionStringName value="EDIEntities" />
          <commandText value="INSERT INTO dbo.Log4NetLog ([Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],[Message],[Exception]) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level,@logger, @message, @exception)" />
          <parameter>
              <parameterName value="@log_date" />
              <dbType value="DateTime" />
              <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
          </parameter>
          <parameter>
              <parameterName value="@thread" />
              <dbType value="String" />
              <size value="255" />
              <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                  <conversionPattern value="%thread" />
              </layout>
          </parameter>
          <parameter>
              <parameterName value="@log_level" />
              <dbType value="String" />
              <size value="50" />
              <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                  <conversionPattern value="%level" />
              </layout>
          </parameter>
          <parameter>
              <parameterName value="@logger" />
              <dbType value="String" />
              <size value="255" />
              <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                  <conversionPattern value="%logger" />
              </layout>
          </parameter>
          <parameter>
              <parameterName value="@message" />
              <dbType value="String" />
              <size value="4000" />
              <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                  <conversionPattern value="%message" />
              </layout>
          </parameter>
          <parameter>
              <parameterName value="@exception" />
              <dbType value="String" />
              <size value="2000" />
              <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout" />
          </parameter>
      </appender>
      <appender name="MyFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.rollingFileAppender">
          <file value="${ProgramData}\CSCFileService\Log\CSCFileService_"/>
          <datepattern value="yyyyMMdd'_${USERNAME}.log'"/>
          <threshold value="ALL"/>
          <appendToFile value="true"/>
          <maximumFileSize value="1MB"/>
          <MaxSizeRollBackups value="10"/>
          <RollingStyle value="size,date"/>
          <staticLogFileName value="false"/>
          <preserveLogFileNameExtension value="true"/>
          <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%identity] | %message%newline"/>
          </layout>
      </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL"/>
      <!--<appender-ref ref="MyFileAppender"/>-->
      <appender-ref ref="EFNetAppender"/>
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

Here is the class from the linked thread to refactor the Entity Connection string:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

namespace CSCFileService
{
    public class EFNetAppender : log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender
    {
        protected override IDbConnection CreateConnection(Type connectionType, string connectionString)
        {
            var factory = (IDbConnectionFactory)Activator.CreateInstance(connectionType);
            var builder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
            var providerConnectionString = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString).ProviderConnectionString;
            IDbConnection instance = factory.CreateConnection(providerConnectionString);
            instance.ConnectionString = providerConnectionString;
            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

After I implemented this to write to the database the memory seems to started to creep up slowly over time which was not happening prior changing from file to database.

Is there a better way configure with entity framework?

Here is the full solution https://github.com/robinhood1995/CSCFileService

Comment: Might be worth checking this actually is the cause. If you set the log level to `OFF` does that stop memory use increasing?

Comment: It seems that log4net doesn't properly dispose the connection. You should do some memory profiling.

Comment: @Stuartd, I did try it off or using the file extender and both seem okay but the write to SQL.

Answer (score 0):

The memory issue was not and issue after all, one of my collogue found it in another project today. As this setting accumulated the writes before writing to the database, so the memory would climb.

NOTE: My apologies for the code above as it was before I made changes as it does show 1 but was changed to 1000.

Original setting accumulating 1000 logs be it writes to the database.
`<bufferSize value="1000" />`
After the change
`<bufferSize value="1" />`

This now has the same memory usage as OFF or file writer appender.

Also I added Purging of database log entries in the database so the database does not keep growing.

This is the original line
`<commandText value="INSERT INTO dbo.Log4NetLog ([Date],[Thread],Level],[Logger],[Message],[Exception]) VALUES (@log_date,@thread, @log_level,@logger, @message, @exception)" />`

This is the changed line to also purge 7 days back.
`<commandText> <![CDATA[INSERT INTO dbo.Log4NetLog ([Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],[Message],[Exception]) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level,@logger, @message, @exception);DELETE FROM dbo.Log4NetLog WHERE Date < DATEADD(Day, -7, GETDATE())]]></commandText>`